# Read-Modify-Write with a Mifare Classic card?

Tags: nfc, mifare

Is it possible to read, modify and write back the modified value during a single 'touch' of a Mifare Classic card? All the tutorials only read or write during a single 'touch', not both. If so, are there any caveats that attention must be paid to?

Comment: Does not really matter that much. I'm asking because I wasn't able to find out if the 'transaction' I described is feasible at all.

Comment: Well, it somewhat does matter as you question is quite broad otherwise and without focus to any specific programming platform likely to be off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With devices I've worked with (android with nxp controllers, hid omnikey and 6055b reader), yes.  Naturally, a read and write will take longer than just a read but can be done in a reasonable amount of time

Comment: In case of android devices and an external hardware which is working as tag. Is it possible if how could you please share some code